# Show that a ring is a Dedekind domain

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, dedekind-domain

Let $R$ be a Dedekind domain and $f \in R[X]$ irreducible over the field of fractions of $R$ such that $f$ and $f'$ generate the unit ideal.

I want to show that $S=R[X]/(f)$ is also a Dedekind domain, which is a Noetherian, integrally closed domain where each prime ideal is maximal.

My attempt was that I wanted show that any prime ideal of $S$ is already maximal. I was trying to do so by using the correspondence between ideals in $S$ and $R[X]$ and aiming at showing that adding any element that is not in the prime ideal already yields that the ideal contains $f'$. However, I didn't succeed. In particular I am not sure where the fact that $R$ itself is a Dedekind domain comes into play.

I would appreciate any hint.

Comment: Is your $f$  monic?

Comment: Yes it is. I forgot to include that.

Answer (score 1):

The conditions you have imply that the module of differentials $\Omega_{S/R} = 0$ which is equivalent to that the morphism $\pi: R \to S$ is Etale. In particular, $\pi$ is unramified.

Now, let $P$ be a maximal ideal of $S$ and $p = P \cap R$. As $R$ is a Dedekind domain, $R_p$ is a regular local ring. In particular, $p_p$ is principal.
As $\pi$ is unramified, 
$$
R_p \to S_P
$$
is an unramified extension of local rings. Thus, $pS_P = PS_P$ is principal. This proves the statement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I am not familiar with Etale or module of differentials. Is there maybe a more elementary proof?

Comment: Neither am I. Unfortunately, I do not know, and it would be intersting to see an elementray proof. I believe what you want to show from the given conditions is that the extension is unramified.